# A question with no answers that has become unanswerable

Tags: discussion

[I saw this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922261/bootstrap-datimetimepicker-v-4-15-35-display-issue). I spoke with the OP in the comments and was able to figure out that the problem was their custom code that was unrelated to the code they posted in their original question. So at this point unless the OP decides to update their question the question is now unanswerable. Its been a week since the ticket has been updated and I assume that the OP has figured out their problem and moved on.

At this point what is the correct course of action to take? Since the question doesn't have an answer and it won't provide much help for whoever comes across it on the future should this question be flagged to be closed? If yes then what should it be closed as? Should the OP be asked to close their question?

I don't have much experience flagging tickets so this is not all that apparent to me and I didn't see a similar question about this so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Close as either "question can not be reproduced", or "questions seeking debugging help...". If the question doesn't have enough in it to base answers on, it should be closed.

Comment: @TZHX That first close reason wouldn't be appropriate.  That would be if the OP can no longer reproduce the problem, the second reason you mentioned is for the case where they didn't provide enough information for us to reproduce the problem that they can still reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the necessary code to reproduce the issue was not included, this off-topic close reason would be appropriate (I have voted as such).

> Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

You also mentioned the question is not useful because of this, so down voting it would also be appropriate if you desire.

Answer (score 3):

If the question doesn't have enough information to answer it, you should be voting to close it.  That's literally exactly why closure exists.  There is a specific close reason just for questions that haven't provided enough information to reproduce the problem:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.